# UITable Cell info only showing when row is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I'm getting some really odd behaviour with a UITableView i'm working on. I have the following code, which loads data from an array into a UITableView. The code seems to work... but the labels only show values when i click on each row. I'm stumped as to why this is happening as i'm pretty sure i didnt have this issue before... but i could be wrong. My code:

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

//@synthesize cRef;

-(void) getData:(NSData *) data {
    NSError *error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) start {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getData:data];
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self start];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [json count];;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"CountryName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"id"];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to change font color of label in cell. Might be text color match with background color.

Answer (score 0):

As @ktpatel said try changing font color

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"CountryName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"id"];

    // set font color
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        // make changes for selected state
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Also I don't see your code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I think you must be doing this in it to see the selected state of UITableViewCell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```